# Compile and Run MySQL++ and C++ example provided in the folder

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, mysql++

I have a question to ask about MYSQL++ and C++ program found in the mysql++-devel package using ubuntu terminal. I tried to run the program resetdb in the provided running program by executing ./exrun resetdb, the system show me the following error message.

Connecting to ''@'localhost', without password...
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'mathias'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

May i know what is the issue with this?

Is it the MYSQL++ not installed correctly?

Hope anyone can shed some light to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of three things.
1 - Create a user in your mysql instance with your user name, e.g. mathias.
2 - Pass credentials to resetdb on the command line, e.g. 
`./simple1 -uSomeMySQLUser -pPasswordForUser`.
3- Change resetdb.cpp to use the credentials of a mySQL user by default if the credentials are not passed. This looks to be around line 89 of resetdb.cpp.

I tested option two above with simple1 using the mySQL root credentials for the development instance I have. When I tried it without a password, I received:
`DB connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.
When I tried it with the proper credentials I received:
`DB connection failed: Unknown database 'mysql_cpp_data'`.
This makes sense as I do not have the 'mysql_cpp_data' database on the instance I am using.